# Getting error while creating groups in Office 365 Admin portal

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have created trial account in MS Dynamic 365 CRM. I have logged and created a new user by making my role into global administrator using Microsoft Office 365 Admin Portal. I have also completed that to successfully. But when I tried to create groups (for user roles) I'm getting error like this

> Message: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information 
>   about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>    or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception 
>    information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation
>    and inspect the server trace logs. 
>   Your request couldn't be completed. Please try again in a few minutes.

I have tried many time still getting same error.

1. How can I fix this ?
2. How can assign user into groups and permissions

Comment: I suggest reaching out to microsoft, something might be broken on their end

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Question subject line - its misleading. Actual security roles creation & assigning users can be done from Settings - Security menu from Dynamics 365 instance url.

But you are facing issues in Office 365 Admin portal. Please try to reach out to contacts in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/contact-technical-support.aspx but am not sure will they support trial orgs or not.